# NSButton and menu

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

How to draw a NSButton that behaves roughly like the `Sent` button and menu seen in the Mail app?  It doesn't have to be exact.  I just want button with a label and disclosure icon with no background until the user hovers and then show a menu underneath.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://loganrockmore.com/code/?LRFilterBar

Comment: Cool, that drawInteriorWithFrame method is the ticket.  I assume the disclosure icon I should draw myself as well?  Thanks!

Comment: Or add it as an image. I did this exactly in the Cappuccino framework. When I get home, I'll send you a link to the gist. You should be able to copy it almost exactly.

Comment: happen to have that gist?  if not, no biggie.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Actually I found it but it's not very useful.